# Lost connection to server executing ALTER TABLE

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I'm trying to execute an `ALTER TABLE` statement in MySQL 5.6. Every time I run the query, it's creating a file with a name like `#sql2-503-918bf.ibd` taking full table size. I don't have enough disk space to run the query, because whenever I try to run it, another `#sql…` file will be created.

Query:

```
ALTER TABLE kt_ticket_message 
    ADD COLUMN from_email varchar(255) NOT NULL COMMENT 'From email';
```

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Table size is 5 GB, database size is 6 GB.

These are parameters in the config file:

```
wait_timeout=30
interactive_timeout=60
max_allowed_packet=1M
```

Can I increase the timeout parameters?

Comment: Try to use `ALGORITHM=INSTANT` if your table do not matches any limitation of [Online DDL Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-online-ddl-operations.html#online-ddl-column-syntax-notes).

Comment: `ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query` isn't usually an indication of a timeout.  It's usually an indication of something more serious, like a crash, which forcibly closes client connections without a response.  Review the MySQL Server's error log.

Comment: Note that your query may still be running.  Try `show full processlist`

Answer (score 3):

Change specific timeouts value to 6000 it's available in all new versions of MySQL Workbench.

> **Open Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out
>   (in seconds): 600**
>
> **Changed the value to 6000.**

Also unchecked limit rows as putting a limit in every time I want to search the whole data set gets tiresome.

Answer (score 1):

Some variants of `ALTER TABLE` need to copy the table over.  In doing so, they create a file named `#sql...`, which will later be renamed to the real table name.  The use of `ALGORITHM=...` is aimed at doing the copy or not.  However, if the `ALTER` cannot work without the copy, it will complain.

`ALTER TABLE` will continue to fail until you have more space.  Or perhaps we can find some other workaround.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and the `ALTER`.

If you have some #sql files left around after `ALTER` crashes, you can safely delete them.

As for increasing the timeout, what client are you using?  I ask because the mysql commandline tool responds (I think) to `interactive_timeout`, while some other clients respond to `wait_timeout`.  `SET both of them higher just in case.

Comment: Where might I find this #sql... file that you speak of?

Comment: In unix, do `find / -name '#sql%'` .

Comment: I'm using a Windows server.

Comment: @Vincent - It will be in the directory where the table is.